# Rewrite engine messes up javascript and css

Tags: php, css, url-rewriting

When I enable the rewrite engine the javascript, css and the images are not included properly, I get error 404 in the console. I'm including the files like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/xtc5m/css/mobile.css">
<script src="templates/xtc5m/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried with including them with a slash in the beginning but then I get error 500

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/templates/xtc5m/css/mobile.css">
<script src="/templates/xtc5m/javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

The rewrite rule I'm using is:

```
RewriteRule (.*)--(.+)\.html$ /product_info.php?products_id=$2 [qsappend,L]
```

The final url which is wrong looks like that:

```
http://www.website.de/category/subcategory/name/templates/xtc5m/mobile.css
```

Comment: You could always include the absolute path eg src="http://www.example.com/abc/foo.js"

Comment: there's no way a rule with `.html$` would ever match a url  with `.css` at the end. Check your server's logs for details about the 500. Since you obviously haven't shown all of the relevant rewrite rules, we can't help you.

Comment: The rewrite rule you show has nothing to do with adding additional `category/subcategory` text into the URI. Regardless, the fact that your match pattern ends with `.html` would prevent rewrites on these static file URI's.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<base>` tag on your page header with your root url.

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```